# finding csh logins and real user names using awk command

Tags: awk

I need to be able to find real user names and csh logins using a awk command.

```
awk -F":" ' {print $5} /etc/passwd
```

the above command gets me the real life username but I need to output only the csh logins from the list.

What can I add to the awk command to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it means that the shell they have deifined is `/bin/csh`. In that case, what you have to do is add the condition of what is defined in the 7th field. If it is `/bin/csh`, print 5th field.

All together:

```
$ awk -F':' '$7=="/bin/csh" {print $5}' /etc/passwd
```

Considering this order:

> [image]

Comment: Check which loggings are set with `$ awk -F: '{print $7}' /etc/passwd | sort -u`. Maybe it is not `/bin/csh` but `/usr/bin/csh`.

Comment: Thank you, the diagram helped

Comment: if I wanted to pipe a command that would count the number of outputs what command could I use?

Comment: You can do it with `wc` (word count).

Comment: More specific the number of users that the awk command produced

Comment: Then `wc -l` will count the lines, that is the results. By the way, if your question is solved consider ticking it a answered!

Comment: I would use the condition `$7 ~ /\/t?csh$/` if  "csh" can include tcsh